# HTML5 LocalStorage: Checking if a key exists

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, local-storage

Why this does not work ?

```
if(typeof(localStorage.getItem("username"))=='undefined'){
    alert('no');
};
```

The goal is to redirect the user from the index page to the login page if not already logged.
Here the `localStorage.getItem("username"))` variable is not defined for the moment.

It's for an ios phonegap app.

Comment: I'm surprised no one said it yet - client side security is highly discouraged. One can simply hit F12 and run `localStorage['username']='admin'` then mess with your website.

Comment: @oriadam I hope that no one is basing the authorization on the localStorage, but it is perfectly fine storing the JWT accessToken in the localStorage.

Answer (score 434, accepted):

Quoting from the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-storage-getitem):

> The getItem(key) method must return the current value associated with the given key. If the given key does not exist in the list associated with the object then this method must **return null.**

You should actually check against `null`.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("username") === null) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was my first mistake !
But it doesnt' work too with if(typeof(localStorage.getItem("username"))===null){
      alert('no')
      };

Comment: Typeof of `null` is `"null"`, not `null` (hope I'm making sense).

Comment: @Gabriel: Remove `typeof(..)`. Check my answer again.

Comment: It's worth noting that the constraints FF (28.0) imposes on its localStorage table allows null values: `CREATE TABLE webappsstore2 (scope TEXT, key TEXT, value TEXT, secure INTEGER, owner TEXT)` while Chrome does not: `CREATE TABLE ItemTable (key TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE, value BLOB NOT NULL ON CONFLICT FAIL)`

Comment: @Derin Nope, what if "username" actually exists, but the stored value is false ?

Comment: @Derin That condition is not a check for existence (as per the question), rather its a check for truth value. In other words, the question asks how to check if the key is present or not; it does not ask how to check if the value against the key is truth-y or false-y. There is a big difference between the two. You are suggesting a mix of both. I hope you understand. For any discussion beyond this, may be we can use a chat room.

Comment: What if null is stored in this key? This kind of check will fail.

Answer (score 78):

This method worked for me:

```
if ("username" in localStorage) {
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('no');
}
```

Comment: this is the best option, in my opinion, as it distinguishes between whether a value has been set and whether it may be false/falsey.

Comment: This solution gives false positives for keys like `length`.  The accepted answer is the correct way to solve this problem.

Comment: I like this solution. It's clean.

Comment: The accepted solution didn't work. Although yours, was completely a life saver! Thank you :-)

Comment: This method will work most of the time, but will catch you out one day. Run `localStorage.__proto__` in the development console and you will see the properties that will conflict.

Answer (score 40):

**Update:**

```
if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty("username")) {
    //
}
```

Another way, relevant when value is not expected to be empty string, null or any other falsy value:

```
if (localStorage["username"]) {
    //
}
```

Comment: It's short for `if( localStorage["username"]==undefined )`

Comment: Not quite - it's a short for `if (localStorage["username"]==undefined || localStorage["username"]==0 || localStorage["username"]==null || localStorage["username"]==false || localStorage["username"]=='')` @AllanRuin

Comment: @oriadam Not quite; you both got it backwards. It's short for `if (localStorage["username"]!==undefined && localStorage["username"]!==0 && localStorage["username"]!==null && localStorage["username"]!==false && localStorage["username"]!=='')`

Comment: @JoL lol you're right :) I'm updating the answer

Comment: This method seems better because it just checks for the key without needlessly returning the key value, e.g., if (localStorage.getItem(key) === null)

Comment: But if "username" is set as any of the falsy values, then  (localStorage["username"]) {
    //
} will pass as truthy because the localStorage stores these values as "string". you will be getting "undefined","null"..etc

Answer (score 19):

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) shows how the `getItem` method is implementated:

```
Object.defineProperty(oStorage, "getItem", {
      value: function (sKey) { return sKey ? this[sKey] : null; },
      writable: false,
      configurable: false,
      enumerable: false
    });
```

If the value isn't set, it returns `null`. You are testing to see if it is `undefined`. Check to see if it is `null` instead.

```
if(localStorage.getItem("username") === null){
```

Comment: Right, I answered to Thrustmaster above. But it doesn't work better with this :/

Comment: It [works for me](http://jsbin.com/osujaf/1/edit).

Comment: @Gabriel — In your comment above you are comparing the `typeof` the value to null. You need to compare the actual value.

Comment: Or use `==` instead of `===` because (for some weird reason) `null==undefined` is true. Then again, you don't need anything, like @Derin answered, you can simply `if (localStorage["username"])`