# Can't read local storage after navigation to a new page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to implement `local storage` for navigating by pages.

I have a web site with some pages, all in one folder.

In one page, I'm setting the local storage:

```
var myObject = { 'id': 1, 'price': 50.0, 'total': 3 };
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

While in the first page, I see the local storage with data- thats OK. But after navigating to the second page, I see that the local storage is empty while trying to read:

```
var localObject = localStorage.getItem('data');
```

Can't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Don't forget to `JSON.parse` the `localObject`!

Comment: So you are doing `console.log(localObject)` and you are not getting the string?

Comment: Yeah, get :"ReferenceError: localObject is not defined"

Comment: Please show us the exact URLs used to access the two pages. Also what browser are you using? This related question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010827 , shows that the value should be `null` if the item does not exist which makes me think your domains are somehow different. Though even then you should receive `null` not `undefined`. In the case of a security violation you should get a hard error thrown. Curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not showing much of the code, but `localStorage` won't throw a reference error if an item does not exist.

It does not matter if you navigated to another domain as the `localStorage` would just return `null` when using `getItem` (`undefined` if you used `localStorage[key]`).

This indicates that you have a problem elsewhere in the code not directly related to `localStorage`.

But you need to show a bit more code and tell us what line the error occur on.

Also as stated in the comments, you would need to `JSON.parse` the data to re-create the object you stringify'ed.