# Checking to see if HTML5 localStorage key exists

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to see if a KEY is stored in the users localStorage, but I every code I seem to try either says its always found regardless of whether its there or not.

JS

```
if (localStorage.getItem(2) === null) {
  alert('not found');
} else {
    alert('Found!');
}
```

The key is the number 2, I have tried wrapping the number in double quotes but regardless of whether the key is there or not it always says its found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 LocalStorage: Checking if a key exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010827/html5-localstorage-checking-if-a-key-exists)

Comment: @morten.c I've used the answer in the question listed, it does not fix the issue.

Comment: what dies calling getItem with an integer return then?

Comment: It will return a stringified array