# how to check for particular object in localstorage

Tags: javascript, json

I have a local storage, where I stored some Objects. As example product1 and product2. How can I check, if there is already a product2 in my storage? Both object have the same key.

Comment: What do you mean by both object have the same key?

Comment: When you use LocalStorage you must give a key and a value. The objects have the same key but different values. And therefore I want to check if a particular object is already in the storage

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010827/html5-localstorage-checking-if-a-key-exists

Comment: unfortunately this is for searching for a key but I need to search for a value

Comment: If both objects have the same key, then when you add the second one to local storage it's going to overwrite the first one. You are better off making the thing that you want to search by your key, as long as those do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expect?  I am getting all the keys and then checking if my product2 already exists or not. If not then I will set it.

```
let keys = Object.entries(localStorage);
//let product2, product2; 
let exists = false;
for(let i = 0 ; i < keys; i++){
   if(object[keys[i]] == product2){
     exists = true;break;
}
}

if(!exists) 
  localStorage.setItem("key",product2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked these:

```
Object.entries(localStorage) //keys
Object.values(localStorage)  // values
```

You can use it the way you want like this:

```
Object.entries(localStorage).find(key=>someEvalFn(key))
```